# Iterate over all symbols in a specific section and obtain their signatures

Tags: c++, linker, ld, symbols

**Target**

I want to resolve the signatures of all symbols linked to a specific section of my binary (not of a shared library).

**What I've done**

In assembly, you can define a `section .example` (NASM syntax) and then link it to a specific location in my binary using:

```
exampleStart = .;
*(.example)
exampleEnd = .;
```

This allows me to iterate over all symbols using the `exampleStart` and `exampleEnd`, as long as I know what they are. For example, if I know that all symbols are methods which require no parameters and return nothing, I can cast them to `void(*)()` and call them as methods.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to define sections in C++, similar to the `.section` syntax in NASM?
2. Can I tell the linker to create something like a symbol table which additionally contains the signatures of the methods?

---

**An example**

In the following I want to show a little example of what I want to achieve (pseudo-C++):

```
SECTION example

void somePrefix_myFunction() {
    // ...
}

int somePrefix_anotherFunction(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

ENDSECTION
```

Somewhere else I then want to be able to iterate over the symbols in this section and obtain the location and the signature of the symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by saying a *binary* you mean an executable file, you generally cannot load symbols from an executable on linux<sup>1</sup> - the C++ code will have to be written or refactored as a (shared) library. Then you will be able to call `dlopen` and `dlsym` to load the relevant symbol.

The question that remains is how do you locate the symbols? When you move away from assembly to C++, and your question is tagged as such, you relinquish most of the control over the symbols' encoding as assembly labels to the compiler and the linker. For example, you will have to consider things such as C++ name mangling. The best approach to enumerate names is to invoke `nm` to list all the symbols and parse the output to extract the symbol names you are interested in - to my knowledge there is no linux API that `nm` calls that you can also call yourself. There is too much specific file format knowledge you will have to account for otherwise, to enumerate the symbols across the different versions of linkers and executables on linux.

---

**EDIT.** You indicated that `nm` is not an option. Given this restriction, I think that you will have to resort to manually maintaining the list of symbols. Otherwise you are looking at duplicating what essentially [**`do_lookup`**](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=elf/dl-lookup.c;hb=HEAD) does in *glibc* as it walks the link map.

Additionally note that you will probably have to mark your symbols with `extern "C"` to avoid name mangling, and to be able to sanely maintain the discussed list of symbols.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Apart from the special case of a PIE executable.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By binary, I mean a plain elf binary (this is loaded by a bootloader as a kernel). So there are no tools like `nm`, another way would be reading the .elf-header by myself, but is there no way to make the linker generate some kind of additional information for my symbols?

Comment: @m4xdev Does it have to be the linker? Since you write the code that loads the binary can't you share the `binary.h` header file with the binary parser and loader? (This is how libraries are typically used in C++  - you have their header files available.)

Comment: The code that is supposed to know the existing linker symbols is actually in the same binary as the symbols. I want to list these symbols and use there names for further use of the methods behind the symbols

Comment: @m4xdev You could have a single known symbol name then, that you load with `dlsym` that returns a list of all the other names that you have to subsequently load with `dlsym`. You can avoid mangling by using `extern "C"` for the methods. When you add a method, you will have to add it to the list. Since this is all one binary, you do know the signatures (as in - function pointer signatures) for all the names, but you have to keep maintaining that list when you add or remove methods.

Comment: Hmm, but maintaining a list of methods is exactly what I want to avoid. Imagine theres a register(char*,void*) method which registers my method somehow. By now, I have to call that method by hand for every new function I add. Like, there is a big "registerAll"-method which then calls register for each function. From another point of view, do you maybe know a way to make the preprocessor list all methods that are for example marked with another macro?

Comment: Given the limited facilities you have I don't think you have much choice. Look what length dlsym `do-lookup` [link](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=elf/dl-lookup.c;hb=HEAD) goes to to try and locate the symbol. Unless you somehow know (without nm) the exact name of the symbol - you'll have to replicate that.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look at the `do_lookup` implementation, but I think that implementing this is not proportionate to maintaining a list of methods. Thank you anyway! :)